Is there a continuous time analog of linear regression for SDEs?
The ordinary linear regression
$$Y_n = \alpha+\beta X_n +\epsilon_n$$
has a closed form solution for $\beta$
$$\beta = \frac{\operatorname{Cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_X^2}.$$
Question:
Is there a continuous time analog? It seems reasonable to model $Y$ in terms of $X$ like
$$dY = \alpha dt + \beta dX+dB$$
in analogy with
$$Y = \alpha+\beta X+\epsilon.$$
Then, we might expect
$$\beta = \frac{[X, Y]}{[X]},$$
where $[X,Y]$ is the quadratic covariation of $X$ and $Y$. But this is not rigorous at all--just thinking analogously.
Some ideas:
a) One idea I tried doing was to let $f(x,y) = (y-\alpha -\beta x)^2$ and apply Ito's lemma, take expectations and optimize over $\beta$. If $Z = f(X_t, Y_t)$ then
$$dZ = f_x dX+ f_y dY +\frac12 f_{xx} d[X]+\frac12 f_{yy} d[Y] +f_{xy} d[X, Y]$$
$$ = -2\beta(Y-\alpha-\beta X)dX +2(Y-\alpha - \beta X)dY +\beta^2 d[X]+2d[Y]+-2\beta d[X,Y].$$
If the first two terms vanished after taking $\mathbb{E}(\cdot)$ or after that and $d/d\beta$ then we would obtain $\beta = [X,Y]/[X]$. But I cannot see any reason why those stochastic differentials should have zero drift or cancel after the two operations.
b) My other idea was to apply stochastic optimal control theory to
$$J(t, x,y, \beta) = \mathbb{E}\left[\int_t^T (Y_s-\alpha_s -\beta_s X_s)^2 | X_t=x, Y_t=y\right],$$
I will add the details once I finish attempting.

In practice you would have discrete observations of $Y$ and $X$. You could regress $Y$ directly on $X$, but if the noise comes from Brownian motion this is not a good idea. It is better in that case to regress the increments of $Y$ on the increments of $X$
